# Counting how much should x and y coordinates change using speed and angle

Tags: java, math

I have 2 values - speed and angle of a body. I need to create a function that uses those two arguments to count how much it should move on X axis and Y axis in a refresh.

Example:

```
public Vector getMoveVectorFromSpeedAndAngle(float speed, float angle) {
  //code I need
}

myBody.x = getMoveVectorFromSpeedAndAngle(myBody.speed, myBody.angle).x;
myBody.y = getMoveVectorFromSpeedAndAngle(myBody.speed, myBody.angle).y;
```

> And what is your question?

How to create such function?

> How do you store angle? In radians or in degrees?

I use degrees, but if it is needed i can switch to radians.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: How do you store `angle`? In radians or in degrees?

Comment: where are you on the plane?  is x the location of the cursor or something else?

Comment: look up how to transform poloar cooridinates to cartesian coordinates. This is pretty much what you need.

Comment: It does not matter. The body is on X `myBody.x` and Y `myBody.y`. @DCR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using radians:

```java
public Vector getMoveVectorFromSpeedAndAngle(float speed, float angle) {
    float x = speed * (float)Math.cos(angle);
    float y = speed * (float)Math.sin(angle);
    return new Vector(x, y);
}
```

And you probably need to increase your body coordinates by given amount, not to assign to it:

```java
myBody.x += getMoveVectorFromSpeedAndAngle(myBody.speed, myBody.angle).x;
myBody.y += getMoveVectorFromSpeedAndAngle(myBody.speed, myBody.angle).y;
```